# Cannot Find Component In Java Faces

Tags: primefaces

I'm working on a Java Servlet web app, and I'm stuck with an error on the page. I've got this `commandButton` :

```
 <p:commandButton update="numbersEventFeedsForm" oncomplete="numbersEventFeedsDialog.show()"
                  icon="ui-icon ui-icon-search" title="view increments" style="height:20px;">
      <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{numbersEvent}" target="#{searchBean.selectedNumbersEvent}"/>
 </p:commandButton>
```

And I've declared my form:

```
<h:form id="numbersEventFeedsForm">
    <p:dialog header="Feeds" widgetVar="numbersEventFeedsDialog" resizable="false" width="1000"
          styleClass="dialog">
         <!-- Etc -->

    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

But I'm receiving the following error:

```
 Sep 13, 2013 4:32:33 PM  com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback visit
 SEVERE: javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier "numbersEventFeedsForm" in view.
```

I'm quite stuck on why the error is occuring. I've read in other questions to ensure I'm prefixing the `update` attribute with the `id` of the `<form>`, but I don't have that attribute so I'm kind of stuck at this point!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference components in JSF ajax? Cannot find component with identifier "foo" in view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier)

Answer (score 0):

@christopher.

First, your form "numbersEventFeedsForm" should stay inside the p:dialog.

If you are working with "p:layout" in full-page on your page, you will also need to define the property "appendTo="@(body)" in your p:dialog, to make it a direct child of the body tag. If don´t make it, you dialog probably will not appear.

Then when try to update the form in a dialog you should use ":numbersEventFeedsForm" to update the form, unless the commandButton are placed inside the referenced "form", in this case you don´t need the ":" prefix.

Try to make this adjustments and see if works..